# Displaying tables using Tab Bar Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Currently I have a tab bar controller set up which displays 5 different pages, i'm trying to display a list of data using the table view, but a different one on each page, the guide i'm using says I needed to CMD Drag the TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER to the APP DELEGATE.  The problem I have is that each of the views has a separate .XIB file, and when I open them to view the content of that particular view, they have no App Delegate option to select in the option viewer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this guide you're referring to an online guide? If so, can you please provide a link? I'm asking because their approach appears rather strange to me, however there may be a deeper meening I fail to see without having read the guide.. thanks!

Comment: Hi Toastor, thanks for the reply, the guide in question is Hour 15 from Sam's Teach Yourself iPad in 24 hours, the exact wording of the step is "To connect to that flowerColorTableViewController outlet created earlier, Control-Drag from the Flower App Delegate to the Flower Table View Controller" -  This is all very good in the tutorial as it displays the table on MainWindow.xib, but i've got 5 seperate .XIBs for 'starters' 'mains' 'desserts' 'drinks' and 'order summary'  -  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link , this tells how to use tabbar controller

```
      http://amaniphone.blog.co.in/2010/11/13/tabbar-and-navifgation-in-iphonetabnav/
Now in every .xib file you created for every tab , drag your tableview  and slect connection inspector 
drag from datasource, delegate pointers to file owner. Then follow the tutorial how to use tableview in iphone app.
```

Comment: To display a table view do I NEED to have a Navigation controller on top of the TabBarController? I've already got the view controller set up for the tab bar with the 5 xib files? Does this mean what i've done won't work?

Comment: no if you does not want to navigate from your table view , then you don't need navigation controller.If you already setup your tabbarcontroller then drag the table view to your views and bind the data to your table view.

Comment: That's what i've been doing, on each of the .xib files for each tab view, for example Starters.xib, I drag on the TableViewController, set the class, but there isn't anywhere to delegate the output too? the AppDelegate is only on MainWindow.xib, so I can't control-drag the data source.